# Django fixtures auto populate time based fields

Tags: django

I am trying to use fixtures to auto populate the fields for the `Category` field. This is how I have defined it:

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    """ TimeStampedModel
    An abstract base class model that provides self-managed "created" and
    "modified" fields.
    """
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Category(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_regional = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)
    is_selected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I run into the following error:

> Problem installing fixture
>   '/Users/varunj/Projects/Backend/Newsybackend/api/fixtures/admin_categories.yaml':
>   Could not load api.Category(pk=1): (1048, "Column 'created_on' cannot
>   be null")

Shouldn't the fixture take care of the subclass fields by themselve, given that they are auto_now anyway?

Comment: Do you already have data in your database? The program won't fix existing data, only new stuff.

Comment: Nope, I flushed it before running loaddata

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?